# How to get percent of category by group in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Apologies if something similar has been asked before, I searched around but couldn't figure out a solution.

My dataset looks like such

```
data1 = {'Group':['Winner','Winner','Winner','Loser','Loser','Loser'],
        'MathStudy': ['Read','Read','Notes','Cheat','Cheat','Read'],
        'ScienceStudy': ['Notes','Read','Cheat','Cheat','Read','Notes']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=data1)
```

[image]

I would like to get a % of total for each category for each group, as shown below. In my dataset the number of winners and losers changes, so a flexible solution is appreciated.
[image]

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) and `normalize` parameter:

```
df1 = df1.melt('Group', var_name='Type')

df2 = pd.crosstab([df1['Group'], df1['Type']], df1['value'], normalize=0)
print (df2)
value                   Cheat     Notes      Read
Group  Type                                      
Loser  MathStudy     0.666667  0.000000  0.333333
       ScienceStudy  0.333333  0.333333  0.333333
Winner MathStudy     0.000000  0.333333  0.666667
       ScienceStudy  0.333333  0.333333  0.333333
```

Last if need `MultiIndex` to columns with remove `value` column name add [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) with [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df2 = df2.rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index()
print (df2)
    Group          Type     Cheat     Notes      Read
0   Loser     MathStudy  0.666667  0.000000  0.333333
1   Loser  ScienceStudy  0.333333  0.333333  0.333333
2  Winner     MathStudy  0.000000  0.333333  0.666667
3  Winner  ScienceStudy  0.333333  0.333333  0.333333
```

Comment: Ah, beat me by 30 seconds :-).

Answer (score 4):

@jezrael's solution is intuitive and what I would do first hand. However, I recently learned that `melt` usually performs poorly. Here's an alternative if performance is important, e.g. in codes that are used repeatedly:

```
g = df1.groupby('Group')
cols = ['MathStudy', 'ScienceStudy']
out = (pd.concat({col:g[col].value_counts(normalize=True) for col in cols})
   .unstack(level=-1, fill_value=0)
)
```

with run time:

```
2.9 ms ± 96.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Compared to `melt` approach:

```
9.44 ms ± 261 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Output:

```
                        Cheat     Notes      Read
MathStudy    Loser   0.666667  0.000000  0.333333
             Winner  0.000000  0.333333  0.666667
ScienceStudy Loser   0.333333  0.333333  0.333333
             Winner  0.333333  0.333333  0.333333
```

**Note**: `pd.crosstab` is essentially `groupby()` with some additional bookkeeping. And `groupby` on two columns are usually a lot slower.

Comment: Nice +1. In my testing `df1.melt('Group', var_name='Type').groupby(['Group', 'Type'])['value'].value_counts(normalize=True).unstack(fill_value=0)` performed considerably better even while using `melt`, though not as fast as your solution, but pretty close.

Comment: @SayandipDutta Yes, that's essentially what crosstab does. The overhead can also be significant.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another alternative:

```
g = df.set_index('Group').stack().str.get_dummies().groupby(level=[0,1]).sum()
g.div(g.sum(axis=1),axis=0).round(2)
```

or

```
df.set_index('Group').stack().groupby(level=[0,1]).value_counts(normalize=True).unstack().fillna(0)
```